# Does any `R` package offer `gnorm`, `hnorm`, and similar? What about other languages?

Tags: r, maximum-likelihood

R typically offers functions prefixed by `d`, `p`, `q`, and `r` for pdf, cdf, inverse cdf, and sampling. These are somewhat useful for inference -- especially MCMC since you're usually sampling and computing densities.

But, for everyday fitting via likelihoods or empirical Bayes, I wish they would have included functions prefixed with `g` for the gradient of the log density w.r.t. the parameters and `h` for the hessian. Does this functionality exist in any R package or any other scientific computing language?

Comment: I think of this question as being about resources for maximum likelihood estimation. If it's too software-focused, feel free to migrate it to another SE site (maybe data science or just Stack Overflow??).

Comment: R-package TMB may perhaps be relevant.

Comment: You should look into `deriv` (and `deriv3`, `D`)

Comment: Looks like `deriv` has a limited collections of functions that it understands, but `dnorm` is indeed among them. Other densities, e.g. `dpois`, are not.